# performing distinct on multiple fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

Let's say we have a collection of docs as follows :

```
[
  {
    "name" : "john",
    "age" : 23,
    "city": "New York",
    "gender": "M"
  },
  {
    "name" : "doe",
    "age" : 30,
    "city": "dubai",
    "gender": "M"
  },
  {
    "name" : "jean",
    "age" : 23,
    "city": "New York",
    "gender": "F"
  }
  {
    "name" : "phil",
    "age" : 24,
    "city": "Ohio",
    "gender": "M"
  }
]
```

Expected output :

```
{
  "name" : ["john","doe","jean","phil"],
  "age" : [23,30,24],
  "city": ["New York","Dubai","Ohio"],
  "gender": ["M","F"]
}
```

I tried using mongodb's distinct , but that will return me just uniques values for one particular field...I dont think we can pass multiple fields in distinct query...

Comment: Do you want only distinct  values of all  keys in any sequence?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) is specifically for these kind of things.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {
    $group: 
    {
      _id: null,
      name: {$addToSet: '$name'},
      age: {$addToSet: '$age'},
      city: {$addToSet: '$city'},
      gender: {$addToSet: '$gender'}
    }
  }
])
```

which gives the output -

```
{ 
  "_id" : null, 
  "name" : [ "phil", "jean", "doe", "john" ], 
  "age" : [ 24, 30, 23 ], 
  "city" : [ "Ohio", "dubai", "New York" ], 
  "gender" : [ "F", "M" ] 
}
```

Comment: Great! Please note that `_id` must be included in the `$group`. One of the only answers on SO with an excellent example.

Comment: what If I want to fetch _id as well??

Comment: how to write same code in spring boot for _id as null , i written below code but it's giving error - any advice please give me  Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Map.class,Aggregation.group("?").addToSet("name").as("name").addToSet("details").as("details"));
       
        AggregationResults<Map> aggregate = template.aggregate(agg, "products", Map.class);